# Octave - Create a matrix of all binary values

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

In Octave, given a number, (say 5), I need to make a matrix of (2^5 X 5) with each row having the binary representation of numbers from 0 to 2^5 - 1 i.e the matrix would be like

> [[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
>
> [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1]]
>
> [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0]]

and so on. Is there any built-in function to do this? Unable to figure out how to do it efficiently? One way I can think of is running a loop and generating the binary value for each value from 0:(2^5-1) and storing it in matrix, but this seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`de2bi` might be in the octave communications toolbox, but I don't have that installed.  The following is a one-line implementation of decimal to binary that may be good enough

```
nums = (1:7)';
bsxfun(@(u,v)bitand(u,v)~=0, [16 8 4 2 1], nums)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

```
N = 5;
result = mod(floor(bsxfun(@rdivide, (0:2^N-1).', 2.^(N-1:-1:0))), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know about octave, but in matlab you have `de2bi`:

```
n = 5;
nums = 0:2^n-1;
b = de2bi(nums);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It gave me what to look up!

Comment: Octave does have `de2bi` in the Communications package, but for both Octave and MATLAB you'd have to use `de2bi(nums, 5, 'left-msb')` to reproduce the OP's sample output. You can also use `dec2bin` without an extra package or toolbox by converting the character string output to numeric like `dec2bin(nums, 5) - '0'`.